# Cambiar un solo caracter de un string - java

Tags: java

Si tengo un `string` de 10 caracteres donde todos estos son 0 y quiero que en el carácter #X y el #2X se cambie el 0 por 1, Hay alguna función para ello?

Comment: ¡Hola! Te recomiendo leer la sección [ask] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Ayudaría mucho que facilitaras un [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el `Substring` para reemplazar los caracteres, de la siguiente forma:

```
int n1 = 2
int n2 = 5
String texto= "0000000000";
String nuevotexto = texto.substring(0,n1-1)+'1'+texto.substring(n1 +1,n2-1)+'1'+texto.substring(n2+1);
```

De esta forma obtendrás `0010010000`. Reemplazando las posiciones 2 y 5 como indican las variables `n1` y `n2`.

Answer (score 1):

Para modificar el caracter en una posición específica puedes usar simplemente

```
char[] tempCharArray = tuString.toCharArray();
tempCharArray[x] = '1'; // Donde 'x' es la posición que buscas.
tuString = String.valueOf(tempCharArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

podrías utilizar el método replace() de la clase StringBuilder

```
    String original = "0000000000";// cadena original original
    System.out.println("Original: " + original);
    int x = 4;// indice del caracter a reemplazar(empieza a contar en cero)
    String nuevo = new StringBuilder(original).replace(x, x+1, "1").toString();// nueva cadena reemplazando el caracter x de la original por 1
    nuevo = new StringBuilder(nuevo).replace(2*x, 2*x+1, "1").toString();// nuevo cadena reemplazando el caracter 2x de la cadena anterior
    System.out.println("Despues de reemplazar en el indice x = " + x + " y 2x = " + (2*x) + " : "  + nuevo);
```

Con esto obtendrías la cadena "0000100010" ya que se reemplaza el caracter en el índice 4 y 8 de la cadena original.

Comment: No necesitas usar dos `StringBuilder`s, basta con el primero. Puedes reducir el código a: `new StringBuilder(original).replace(x, x+1, "1").replace(2*x, 2*x+1, "1").toString()`, esto es más eficiente tanto en memoria como en tiempo de ejecución.